# Google Chrome search engine settings

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

GC version: 18

Default GC search engine setting looks like this:

```
{google:baseURL}search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s
```

It's searching on Google Search in my country. How do I change that to always use Google US? I've tried to set the default setting to:

```
http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=%s
```

This works except when using some symbols like plus sign '**+**', since it's not escaped. For example, if I type '**123+456**' in address bar, it will be interpreted as `http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=123+456`, which would do google search '**123 456**', not the calculation result **579** I was looking for. Another example is that searching '**C++ bit operation**' would get google search '**C bit operation**'. This issue makes address bar searching not working in some cases. I was wondering if there's any way to resolve this?

Comment: Windows, Mac OS or Linux?

Comment: Windows 7. Chrome v18

Comment: did you allready tried this one? http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/discuss-chrome/PsyzIEtHw5U

Comment: Yep, the %s variable can only take non-url specific characters, meaning that '+', '&' are all treated as part of url.

Comment: did you try `http://www.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTrialGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s` ?

Comment: IE6 allows you to specify your own set of character-substitutions for each custom search engine. Take that Chrome and Firefox!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Rob's comment, set the default search engine to `https://www.google.com/search?{google:RLZ}{google:acceptedSuggestion}{google:ori‌​ginalQueryForSuggestion}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:instantFieldTri‌​alGroupParameter}sourceid=chrome&ie={inputEncoding}&q=%s` to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to edit the file

```
Local State.txt
```

in your chrome directory.

Chrome's default directory can be found out here : chrome://version/ [Copy and paste this in the URL bar]  (The profile path)

Edit the local state file there and replace google.xxx (Your country's extension) with google.com in the browser field "last_known_google_url" and "last_prompted_google_url"

[image: googleeeee]

Replace google.co.in with google.com

Comment: This seems not to be working. My last_known_google_url and last_prompted_google_url are both "www.google.com". I was trying to grep 'baseURL' in default directory as {google:baseURL} looks like a environment variable in the configuration. But I didn't find one.

Comment: @Stan I changed it to google.com and it worked fine for me, I am using Chromium not chrome, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thank you, you can't imagine how much stress this was producing!! It is amazing how much the results suck in Spanish for technical problems and programming!! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**You better do the following:**
How to fix:

1. Open "C:\Users{your_user_account}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data" folder.
2. Open "**Local State**" file.
3. Add/Edit these in the node "browser":

   `"last_known_google_url": "https://www.google.com/", 
   "last_prompted_google_url": "https://www.google.com/",`
4. Open "Default/**Preferences**" file.
5. Add/Edit these in the node "browser":

   `"last_known_google_url": "https://www.google.com/", 
   "last_prompted_google_url": "https://www.google.com/",`

> How node "browser" looks like:
>     },
>     "browser": {
>        //your code here

I figured that out after a lot of investigation in my Chrome installation directory, as I couldn't find any workable solution by Googling the problem, so I prefer to share it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a space between the terms, i.e. 123 + 567, although it works on my version of chrome even without them.